# CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. in Mac air m1

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-ios

aninarafath@ANINs-MacBook-Air ios % pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the **Podfile** and 2 total pods installed.

[!] **CocoaPods** did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

any one know why getting this error?

[image]

pode file

[image]

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the mechanics of flutter and can be ignored.
Read the corresponding github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73845

Answer (score -1):

Just go to project settings and then the Info tab in Xcode
And set the configurations setting to None for the Pods-related targets,

Close the Xcode and Then run pod install again.

Comment: This is not a proper solution. Read this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73845